# Delete all folders on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to delete all node_modules folders and vendors from my computer to free up some space.
I found some code on one forum that looks like:

```
FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" rm -rf "%d"
```

ofc when I run this code I receive error like

> 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

So I tried like this

```
FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" del /F /Q "%d"
```

It is doing something but it's not deleting folders, without /Q is asking me Am I sure, and still nothing.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The command __DEL__ is for deleting __files__ as it can be read by opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and running `del /?` to get output the help explaining this in first sentence. The command `help` outputs a list of [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) with a brief description including the command __RD__ to remove a directory. For help on __RD__ run in cmd window `rd /?`. And for help on __FOR__ run `for /?`. `rm` is a Linux shell command to remove files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `rmdir` not `rm`

https://www.computerhope.com/rmdirhlp.htm

For folders with files in them you'll need `deltree`

https://www.computerhope.com/deltree.htm

Comment: Yes, but this will delete only empty folders inside node_modules. When I try this it's giving The directory is not empty. But when I run like rmdir /s /q for some files I have access is denied. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `FOR /d /r . %d in (node_modules) DO @IF EXIST "%d" rmdir /S "%d"`.
Pay attention to S option. `deltree` is not available in basic cmd. Its deprecated.

Comment: Yes I see that I can't install deltree, but when I run this command I'm receiving Access is denied for some folders. How to fix that

Comment: Type cmd in start menu and right click on cmd - Run cmd as administrator.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it's not locating node_modules... Because when I run as admin it's like C:\WINDOWS\system32 when I run command it's doing nothing actually. Tried to relocate in /Users/{USER} but same access denied

Answer (score 0):

1) start cmd.exe with admins rights: **`run as admin`**

2) go to the folder target: **`cd /d "c:\folder\where\node_modules\are"`**

3) kill node process: **`%__APPDIR__%taskkill.exe /f /im node.exe`**

4) run your command line:

```
for /d /r . %d in (node_modules)do @if exist "%~d\" rmdir /q /s "%~d\*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **git bash** to delete the `node_modules` folder. Navigate to parent folder from file explorer, open **git bash** and run below command;

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.computerhope.com/rmdirhlp.htm), just use:

```
rmdir /s /q node_modules
```

The **/s** is used to say: please remove  *all directories and files* contained in '**node_modules**', which means remove the complete tree.

The **/q** is used to say: don't ask if I want to remove the directory tree

**Alternative:** install **rimraf** the Unix command **rm rf** that works on windows.

```
npm i rimraf
```

To remove a node_modules or another tree just enter:

```
rimraf node_modules
```

and you are done